# rails "rake test" error "param is missing".

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm having some troubles testing my rails app.  I'm just learning how to test, so I think this should be no problem for you.
I have this product schema:

```
create_table "products", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string   "title"
  t.text     "description"
  t.string   "image_url"
  t.decimal  "price"
  t.datetime "created_at",  null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at",  null: false
end
```

this model:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :title, :description, :image_url, presence: true
  validates :price, numericality: {greater_than_or_equal_to: 0.01}
  validates :title, uniqueness: true
  validates :image_url, allow_blank: true, format: {
    with: %r{\.(gif|jpg|png)\Z}i,
    message: 'must be a URL for GIF, JPG or PNG image.'
  }
end
```

and this controller:

```
   #some lines omitted...
  def create
    @product = Product.new(product_params)
    respond_to do |format|
    if @product.save
      format.html { redirect_to @product, notice: 'Product was successfully created.' }
    format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @product }
  else
    format.html { render :new }
    format.json { render json: @product.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
private
def product_params
  params.require(:product).permit(:title, :description, :image_url, :price)
end
```

So, I'm runing this test:

```
setup do
  @product = products(:one)
  @update = {
    title: 'Lorem Ipsum',
    description: 'Wibbles are fun!',
    image_url: 'lorem.jpg',
    price: 19.95
}
end

test "should create product" do
  assert_difference('Product.count') do
  process :create, method: :post, params: @update
end
```

But I get 0 failures with 1 error.

```
Error:
ProductsControllerTest#test_should_create_product:
ActionController::ParameterMissing: param is missing or the value is empty: product
app/controllers/products_controller.rb:72:in `product_params'
app/controllers/products_controller.rb:27:in `create'
test/controllers/products_controller_test.rb:30:in `block (2 levels) in <class:ProductsControllerTest>'
test/controllers/products_controller_test.rb:29:in `block in <class:ProductsControllerTest>'
```

I must say that i'm just upgrade rails 4.2 to 5.0.0.1. and I'm following the "agile development with rails 5" book, but the test doesn't work if I do it like the book says, I guess rails has changed in someway since the book was write.
 I have tried to do this in many ways but I could not figure it out. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that the `@update` has to look like this

```
@update = {
  product: {
    title: 'Lorem Ipsum',
    description: 'Wibbles are fun!',
    image_url: 'lorem.jpg',
    price: 19.95 
  }
}
```